# Why Do You Need To Minus 1 When Determining The Maximum Number N Bits Can Represent?

Tags: binary

So in binary to find the largest number you can represent given N amount of bits, you would use:

> 2^N - 1

But why the -1. To try understand it i created a 3 Bit systems and tried some examples:

2^1 = (2) - 1

- 0 0 1 --> 1

2^2 = (4) - 1

- 0 1 0 -->  2
- 0 1 1 -->  3

2^3 = (8) - 1

- 1 0 0 -->  4
- 1 0 1 -->  5
- 1 1 0 -->  6
- 1 1 1 -->  7

So it all works out as planned, but why the -1. This probably sounds like a stupid question but as you can see above i have done a fair amount of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can represent 0 which always takes up one spot in all the permutations.

Answer (score 2):

The research shown should reveal the answer already, but you have forgotten about the zero.

Three bits are able to represent `2^3` different *values*. The *smallest* value is *zero*, so the *largest* must be `2^3-1`.

Note that if you use a different system (such as signed binary), the *smallest* and *largest* value may change, but the *count* of values does not.